# Finding a matrix associated to a function with respect to two bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vector-spaces

The question is as follows:

$V_1$ is the vector space of 2x2 matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ and $V_2$ is the vector space of 3x2 matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ with bases

$A = $ ($\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,
 $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,
 $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$)

and

$B = $ ($\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,
($\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,
($\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,
($\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,
($\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$
($\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$)

respectively. Let $f: V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ be the linear map given by

$f(M) = $ $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & -8 \\ -1 & 7 \\ 2 & 3 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \cdot M$

Find the matrix associated to $f$ with respect to the bases $A$ and $B$.

What I have right now:

The matrix is the unique 3x2 matrix $D$ whose function (multiplying it with any vector from $V_1$) is the linear map * $\phi_B^{-1}(f(\phi_A)): V_1 \rightarrow V_2$. I know that if it were vector spaces of mx1 matrices, I could place the vectors from $A$ as columns of a matrix, find the inverse and then use that the matrix associated to $f$ with respect to the bases A and B equals $B^{-1}CB$, but here I'm completely lost.

So I tried to rewrite the basis of $V_1$, $A$ as

$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

of which the inverse is the same, so the basis $B$ could be written as

$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ and it would follow that the matrix associated to $f$ with respect to the bases A and B equals $B^{-1}CB$ =

$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ \end{smallmatrix})$$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix})$,

which doesn't exist since the # of columns of the left matrix don't equal the amount of rows of the middle one and the amount of columns of the middle matrix doesn't equal the amount of rows of the right matrix.

I'm probably committing a cardinal sin in linear algebra, can someone help me out?

* $\phi_C: F^n \rightarrow W$ is the unique linear map that sends the $j-th$ standard vector $e_j$ to $w_j$, where $e$ is the standard generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V_1$ has dimension $4$ and $V_2$ has dimension $6$, hence the matrix of $f$ is a $6\times 4$ matrix. The columns of this matrix are the coordinates, in the standard basis of $V_2$, of images of the standard basis of $V_1$.

Explicitly,
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}&\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
2&0\\-1&0\\2&0
\end{bmatrix}&
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}&\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
0&2\\0&-1\\0&2
\end{bmatrix}&
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}&\mapsto
\begin{bmatrix}
-8&0\\7&0\\3&0
\end{bmatrix}&
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}&\mapsto
\end{align*}
whence the matrix of $f$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&-8&0\\0&2&0&-8\\-1&0&7&0\\0&-1&0&7\\2&0&3&0\\0&2&0&3
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I was aware I could do this with vectors that had 1 column, but having a vector with 2 or 3 columns really threw me off. Thank you!